# Custom Post Types Conditional Statement in PHP

Tags: php, conditional-formatting

I have a chunk of PHP code that works fine, but I want to alter it and I can’t figure out the logic. I have a movie review site (DVD) and I list the features in a box. Using the code below, I can list a feature (in this instance, a trailer for the movie). I want to alter it so that if it doesn’t have this feature, it displays a greyed out box and if it has it, to display an “active” box.  The greyed out class is “minus” the active is “plus”.

CODE

```
    <?php
    global $wp_query;
    $postid = $wp_query->post->ID;
    if( get_post_meta($postid, ‘trailer’, true)) { ?>
    <li><i class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-lg"></i> <?php echo 
    get_post_meta($postid, ‘trailer’, true);?>Theatrical Trailer</li>
    <?php } 
    elseif( get_post_meta($postid, 'ecpt_trailer', true)) { 
    ?>
    <li><i class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-lg"></i> <?php echo 
    get_post_meta($postid, 'ecpt_trailer', true);
    ?> Theatrical Trailer </li>
<?php } ?>
```

This code is working, just not the way I want it to. I need that “extra step” to show the class.

The active class is:

```
 <li><i class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-lg"></i> <?php echo 
    get_post_meta($postid, ‘trailer’, true);
    ?>Theatrical Trailer</li>
```

The inactive class is:

```
<li class=”minus”><i class="fa fa-minus-circle fa-lg"></i> <?php echo 
get_post_meta($postid, ‘trailer’, true);
?>Theatrical Trailer</li>
```

So, ideally if the DVD had a trailer, it would read:

```
<li><i class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-lg"></i> Theatrical Trailer</li>
```

And if it did not have a trailer, it would read:

```
<li class=”minus”><i class="fa fa-minus-circle fa-lg"></i> Theatrical Trailer</li>
```

Hopefully all of that makes sense. Also if there is a more efficient way of doing this (meaning my code above is slower than it could be) feel free to update it!

P.S. - I have some older custom post types and some newer, the older are "trailer" and the newer are "ecpt_trailer" so I have to check the "old" reviews as well as the "new" reviews to ensure they all look the same. Again, if there's a more efficient way to do this, I'm all ears.

Comment: watch the quotes, you will get in to all kind of mess using non standard `"` and `'` in your code

Comment: I think I typed this up in Word. I assure you all the quotes are regulation in the PHP.